# Bootstrap Tabbable Issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a html page as **B.html** with tab navigation. I made tabs tabbable in my html page as below.

```
<div class="tabbable">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Section 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Section 2</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
      <p>I'm in Section 1.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
      <p>Howdy, I'm in Section 2.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have another html page as **A.html**. In **A.html** page, there are 2 `a tags` as **T1** and **T2**. When i click **T1**, i need to redirect to **B.html** and show content own to **Tab 1** and When i click **T2**, i need to redirect to **B.html** and show content own to **Tab 2**.

I have tried as below.

```
<a href="http://www.abc.com/B.html#tab1">T1</a>
<a href="http://www.abc.com/B.html#tab2">T2</a>
```

But this not worked. it always select tab1. How can i solve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of javascript/jquery for this, read the hash value and open desired tab:

**Markup:**

```
<div class="tabbable">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id='my_tab'>
    <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Section 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Section 2</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
      <p>I'm in Section 1.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
      <p>Howdy, I'm in Section 2.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JQUERY:**

```
    var tabs = $("#my_tab");
    if (window.location.hash === '#tab1') {
        $('#my_tab a:first').tab('show');     
    }
    else if(window.location.hash === '#tab2') {
        $('#my_tab a:last').tab('show');     
    }
```

The above is very general code, can be optimize as per your need.

Comment: what is `#myTab` in `$('#myTab a:first').tab('show');` ? i think it should be `my_tab`. correct it and i'll accept your answer as correct answer.

Comment: This scroll page to where tabs is in the html page. it hide page header. can i avoid it ? can i normally load the page with out scrolling to tabs position ?

Comment: I did't get this: it hide page header. Do you have fixed header?

Comment: So what would you do, if there is say 20 tabs? Or a dynamically and varied number of tabs?

Comment: @davidkonrad: This is just basic answer to provide an idea, obviously you can generalize it as per your requirement. Also I appreciate your answer. Nice One:)

Comment: @kalpeshpatel tabs in middle of page. so when using above approach, page load and scroll to middle of the page (where tabs in the page). so header is hiding. it is fixed header.

Comment: Ok, if I am not wrong you don't want your tabs to get focused, just you wanted to have appropriate tab be opened. Is it what you wanted?

Comment: For that I think you can try:  window.scrollTo(0);

Comment: OK. +1 for using `window.location.hash`!! Totally forgot that :-)

Comment: I used `$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");`. work as charm. thanks :)